# asadmin start-domain fails when remote JMS queue is unreachable

Tags: glassfish, jms, asadmin

I have 2 servers A and B running a glassfish 3.1.2.2 application server on them. Both use a JMS queue for communication, which works fine so far. If the network connection breaks for any reason, I can see in the logs of server B (the one configured to connect to the remote queue of A) that it tries to reconnect and is actually always successful in doing so as soon as A is up again.

But the problem is, that if I try to restart the glassfish instance on B *while* server A is unreachable, the startup process will fail after some retries and remains stuck in a kind of undefined/unusable state, i.e. the java process is started, some ports are open but the applications are not started - not even the administration console.

IMHO glassfish startup process should not wait for the queues to connect, this should be done in some kind of background process.

Has anyone of you experienced something similar? Is there anything I can configure/tune to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it seems to have fixed itself :(
After restarting the computer,removing the deployed ear and deploying it again it just worked. I haven't experienced this behaviour since then.